# How to add splash screen for iOS using Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, splash-screen, progressive-web-apps, vuetify.js

Hi Im trying to create a splash screen for my Vuetify PWA but its not working. I'm personally using an iPhone XS and its not working for whatever reason.

This tutorial works on my phone and I followed what he did https://medium.com/@applification/progressive-web-app-splash-screens-80340b45d210

However he isn't using vue or Vuetify which could be the difference. I looked at this one as well who is using vue but that method didn't seam to work for me either just adding the splashscreens in the manifest under icons https://medium.com/@eder.ramirez87/modern-pwa-with-vue-cli-3-vuetify-firestore-workbox-part-1-974383be5540

Honestly I didn't read his whole project so maybe he doesn't even have splash screens although the links look to be called splash screen. his repository is https://github.com/Eder87rh/cropchien/blob/master/public/manifest.json

this is my pwa https://rosedronesolutions.com so just to be clear the splash screen is what should be shown when you click on the app and it hasn't loaded your app yet.

I am curious about what the right screen resolutions I should be using both in the splash screen as well as iPhone media size because there is like resolution and logical resolution but whatever I just did what that guy did that worked in his sample https://pwa-splash.now.sh/ but didn't work in mine.

To be honest I should probably know how to share my repository but I don't. Its on code commit but maybe you don't need the whole thing anyway. Here is the stuff I added to my index.html and then added the splashscreens in a folder in public called splashscreens

```
<link href="splashscreens/iphone5_splash.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="splashscreens/iphone6_splash.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="splashscreens/iphoneplus_splash.png" media="(device-width: 621px) and (device-height: 1104px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="splashscreens/iphonex_splash.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="splashscreens/iphonexr_splash.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="splashscreens/iphonexsmax_splash.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="splashscreens/ipad_splash.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="splashscreens/ipadpro1_splash.png" media="(device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="splashscreens/ipadpro3_splash.png" media="(device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="splashscreens/ipadpro2_splash.png" media="(device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Rose Drone" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
```

Comment: You can use [PWACompat](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/pwacompat) for this. Checkout [this PWA starter project](https://github.com/kefranabg/bento-starter) if you want a croncrete integration example

Comment: Well. That works! Idk what it's doing that I wasn't. I will be disecting these for the next couple of days to figure them out. Thanks!